# How to assign value from struts tag to a java variable in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have written action class and able to get the value and print in jsp page using struts tag. But I want to assign the value to a Java variable in java tag.

Below is code to display value from action class on jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<s:property value="name"/>
```

I want to assign above value to a java variable, below is the java variable:

```
<% String name;%>
```

How can I assign value that is fetched using struts tag to the variable that is used in java tag?

Comment: Why do you want to use scriptlets in the first place?

Comment: @DaveNewton I want to assign some value that I have fetched from database to a cookie in my website. Also I want to use another value to display a message based of if else conditions.

Comment: Scriptlets are almost always awful; you can set the cookie in the Java code, and use tags/conditionals for the if/else.